Feature selection and Prediction in DGL Link Prediction
I am new to this field and I am trying to do link-prediction using DGL on the given graph. I am struggling to create features for the graph and at last to do inference. My pipeline is working, I have used the code provided on - DGL_Link_Prediction. I have tried to read many tutorials and blogs but no one has taught me how to do link prediction between two nodes (whether a link exists or not), say node 89 and node 30.
This is my code-
src = [...] #list of source node
dst = [...] #list of destination node
src_tensor = torch.tensor(src)
dst_tensor = torch.tensor(dst)
g = dgl.graph((src_tensor, dst_tensor))
g = g.int()
g = dgl.to_bidirected(g)

#creating features (need help here) (a better approach)
nx_g = g.to_networkx()

betweenness = nx.betweenness_centrality(nx_g)
closeness = nx.closeness_centrality(nx_g)

centrality_features = torch.tensor([[betweenness[n], closeness[n]] for n in nx_g.nodes()])
g.ndata['feat'] = centrality_features

# Split edge set for training and testing
u, v = g.edges()

eids = np.arange(g.number_of_edges())
eids = np.random.permutation(eids)
test_size = int(len(eids) * 0.1)
train_size = g.number_of_edges() - test_size
test_pos_u, test_pos_v = u[eids[:test_size]], v[eids[:test_size]]
train_pos_u, train_pos_v = u[eids[test_size:]], v[eids[test_size:]]

# Find all negative edges and split them for training and testing
adj = sp.coo_matrix((np.ones(len(u)), (u.numpy(), v.numpy())))
adj_neg = 1 - adj.todense() - np.eye(g.number_of_nodes())
neg_u, neg_v = np.where(adj_neg != 0)

neg_eids = np.random.choice(len(neg_u), g.number_of_edges())
test_neg_u, test_neg_v = neg_u[neg_eids[:test_size]], neg_v[neg_eids[:test_size]]
train_neg_u, train_neg_v = neg_u[neg_eids[test_size:]], neg_v[neg_eids[test_size:]]

train_g = dgl.remove_edges(g, eids[:test_size])

from dgl.nn import SAGEConv

# ----------- 2. create model -------------- #
# build a two-layer GraphSAGE model
class GraphSAGE(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, in_feats, h_feats):
        super(GraphSAGE, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = SAGEConv(in_feats, h_feats, 'mean')
        self.conv2 = SAGEConv(h_feats, h_feats, 'mean')

    def forward(self, g, in_feat):
        h = self.conv1(g, in_feat)
        h = F.relu(h)
        h = self.conv2(g, h)
        return h

train_pos_g = dgl.graph((train_pos_u, train_pos_v), num_nodes=g.number_of_nodes())
train_neg_g = dgl.graph((train_neg_u, train_neg_v), num_nodes=g.number_of_nodes())

test_pos_g = dgl.graph((test_pos_u, test_pos_v), num_nodes=g.number_of_nodes())
test_neg_g = dgl.graph((test_neg_u, test_neg_v), num_nodes=g.number_of_nodes())

import dgl.function as fn

class DotPredictor(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, g, h):
        with g.local_scope():
            g.ndata['h'] = h
            # Compute a new edge feature named 'score' by a dot-product between the
            # source node feature 'h' and destination node feature 'h'.
            g.apply_edges(fn.u_dot_v('h', 'h', 'score'))
            # u_dot_v returns a 1-element vector for each edge so you need to squeeze it.
            return g.edata['score'][:, 0]

model = GraphSAGE(train_g.ndata['feat'].shape[1], 16)
# You can replace DotPredictor with MLPPredictor.
#pred = MLPPredictor(16)
pred = DotPredictor()

def compute_loss(pos_score, neg_score):
    scores = torch.cat([pos_score, neg_score])
    labels = torch.cat([torch.ones(pos_score.shape[0]), torch.zeros(neg_score.shape[0])])
    return F.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(scores, labels)

def compute_auc(pos_score, neg_score):
    scores = torch.cat([pos_score, neg_score]).numpy()
    labels = torch.cat(
        [torch.ones(pos_score.shape[0]), torch.zeros(neg_score.shape[0])]).numpy()
    return roc_auc_score(labels, scores)

# ----------- 3. set up loss and optimizer -------------- #
# in this case, loss will in training loop
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(itertools.chain(model.parameters(), pred.parameters()), lr=0.01)

# ----------- 4. training -------------------------------- #
all_logits = []
for e in range(100):
    # forward
    h = model(train_g, train_g.ndata['feat'])
    pos_score = pred(train_pos_g, h)
    neg_score = pred(train_neg_g, h)
    loss = compute_loss(pos_score, neg_score)

    # backward
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()

    if e % 5 == 0:
        print('In epoch {}, loss: {}'.format(e, loss))

# ----------- 5. check results ------------------------ #
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
with torch.no_grad():
    pos_score = pred(test_pos_g, h)
    neg_score = pred(test_neg_g, h)
    print('AUC', compute_auc(pos_score, neg_score))
pred_src=[45,68,843,234,2,457,2]
pred_src=[67,89,5,45,346,12,698]

#Now how to do prediction for a link between node 45 and 67 or any other. I have a list of edges for which I have to do the link prediction.

Thanks
